# Assign SSL Certificate to Website After Binding - Powershell

Tags: powershell, http, https, binding, ssl-certificate

Good day. How can I assign SSL Certificate to website automatically after binding with http and https?

I have this code, it binds http and https but it doesn't assign the SSL Certificate. Maybe you can help me. Thank you in advance.

```
 $thumbprint="########################################"
 $binding = @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=$ip+":80:"+$iisAppNameBinding}
 new-item $iisAppName -type site –physicalPath $directoryPath -bindings $binding

 $newBinding = (
      @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=$ip+":80:"+$iisAppNameBinding},
      @{protocol="https";bindingInformation=$ip+":443:"+$iisAppNameBinding;certificateStoreName="MY";certificateName=$thumbprint})
 Set-itemproperty $iisAppName -name bindings -value $newBinding
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your certificate is under *cert:LocalMachine\My*

```
import-module webadministration
$computerName = $Env:Computername
$domainName = $Env:UserDnsDomain
New-WebBinding -Name "MyWebSite" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match "CN\=$Computername\.$DomainName" } | select -First 1 | New-Item IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
```

Reference Link for another method: [powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-configuring-ssl-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in)